# Get certificate from keystore not based on alias name in java

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, keystore, mscapi

I am getting certificates from the keystore based on alias name using the below code,

```
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");

    Enumeration aliasesEnum = keyStore.aliases();

    while(aliasesEnum.hasMoreElements())
    {
       aAliasName = (String)aliasesEnum.nextElement();  
       X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(aAliasName);
    }
```

Is there any way to get aliases from the current token instead of getting from keystore?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have another problem now, then create a new question. It is bad practice to change your question after it has been answered, because then the answers don't match the question anymore.

Comment: @Vijaya, as Omikron pointed out, please revert your question and open a new question for your new issue. So the answer(s) below would match the question, and people visiting this question in the future know what would solve their problem. You can accept the answer which solved your issue, thus closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a particular certificate other than knowing the alias.

The best practice would be to have unique alias in your use case, so you will know which certificate you are getting.

If you are storing the Certificate through the KeyStore api, you can do a `containsAlias(alias)` to see if the alias already exists before you save.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. i fixed the issue by following this link https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/software/sd-dss/issue/problem-possible-keystore-aliases-collision-when-using-mscapi.

Comment: Now i am having another problem can you please check updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Normally alias names are unique. This is a problem specific to MSCAPI keystore. There are several bug reports (some of them very old) regarding this issue:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=2162058

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6483657

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058544

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6672015

Follow the last link, it contains a workaround. You basically have to modify the alias names via reflection API into something unique (see code in link). Not exactly a clean solution, but unfortunately the only way.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. i fixed the issue by following this link https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/software/sd-dss/issue/problem-possible-keystore-aliases-collision-when-using-mscapi.

Comment: I think this is same as last link you have provided.

Comment: Now i am having another problem can you please check updated question.